# mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, fastcgi

I have been struggling for weeks with this error:

```
(32)Broken pipe: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

followed sometimes with this error:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in 
handle_request_ipc function
```

I have to say that i'am not familier with FastCGI, so I've googled everywhere and tried every possible solution, but none really worked. i.e. like setting
**FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess to 500**

Can anyone please explain to me what does this Error exactly means? and maybe have any suggestions.

I'm running on a VM, debian Jessie with PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811543/php-and-mod-fcgid-ap-pass-brigade-failed-in-handle-request-ipc-function